# Why inactive concurrent queue blocking the full function execution?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Step 1: Declare a concurrent queue .initialInactive

Step 2: Call the function having a sync closure.

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.semaphore", attributes: [.concurrent, .initiallyInactive])
func call() {
    print("1")
    print("7")
    concurrentQueue.sync {
    }
    print("13")
}
```

Output: 1, 7

For the below execution

```
func call() {
    print("1")
    print("7")
    concurrentQueue.activate()
    concurrentQueue.sync {
    }
    print("13")
}
```

Output: 1, 7, 13

Comment: `Normally, a newly created queue schedules submitted blocks for execution immediately. Use this attribute to prevent the queue from scheduling blocks until you call its activate() method.`? From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/attributes/2300062-initiallyinactive. So it's blocking the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called with with `sync`, so the call will wait until the block is scheduled and completes. The queue is inactive, so it cannot schedule blocks. Therefore, the block can't complete, and the `sync` can't return. Is there a different behavior you're expecting from `sync`?

This construct is useful if you want all the processes to wait for some condition before starting. For example, you might make an inactive queue that guards access to something that needs to initialize (logging-in for example, or reading configuration from disk). Once that has initialized, it can call `.activate()`, and all of these other processes will start. If the system is already initialized, the `.sync {}` call will return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wandering why the last line of the func is not executing. What is happening under the hood? 

Comment: It's blocking, waiting for `.sync()` to return. `.sync()` never returns in your example. It's like calling `while condition {}`. If condition is false and is never set to true, lines after that won't execute.