# Do you have to manually specify that your DispatchQueue is serial?

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I know that you can create a concurrent queue by doing the following:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Awesome Queue", attributes: .concurrent)
```

But I don't see an alternative enum for creating serial queues, something like:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Awesome Queue", attributes: .serial)
```

[The only other possible option seems to be `.initiallyInactive`, am I missing something?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/attributes)

How do I specify in Swift that I want a serial queue?

**Note that I am using the above queues like this:**

```
queue.async {
    // do task 1
}

queue.async {
    // do task 2
}

// expect task 1 to start
// expect task 1 to finish
// expect task 2 to start
// expect task 2 to finish
```

Comment: dont use that attribute. If u dont use it it will execute in FIFO order

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300059-init)’s description of the `attributes` parameter, “The attributes to associate with the queue. Include the `concurrent` attribute to create a dispatch queue that executes tasks concurrently. If you omit that attribute, the dispatch queue executes tasks serially.”

Comment: @Rob Yeah, thanks. I must've overlooked this detail.

Comment: No worries. I was just trying to provide an authoritative reference…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Awesome Queue", attributes: .concurrent)`

When you use `DispatchQueue` with `.concurrent` attribute. It will execute in a concurrent manner.

`let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Awesome Queue")`

But if this attribute is not present, the queue schedules tasks serially in first-in, first-out (FIFO) order. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/attributes/2300052-concurrent) for more details.

Btw :  `.initiallyInactive` attribute is use to prevent the queue from scheduling blocks until you call its `activate()` method.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on your last sentence regarding `.initiallyInactive`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328049/why-inactive-concurrent-queue-blocking-the-full-function-execution check the answer here

Answer (score 1):

Serial is the default. It isn't available as an option since if it was, you could specify both [.serial, .concurrent] which wouldn't make much sense. See [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/3927) for more info.